# How to interrupt in fetching data from DB

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

We use LINQ to SQL in our project. One of the tables is "Users" used in every action in the project.

Recently we were said to add "IsDeleted" column to the table and consider that column in every data fetching in LINQ to SQL queries.

We wouldn't want to add "WHERE IsDeleted = Fasle" to all queries.

Is it possible "to interrupt" to LINQ after the data was fetched but before sending further to code in the project?

Comment: if you want to filter out `IsDeleted` then you **have** to add it, the question is, where do you add it? ...also "interrupt" is quite a misleading word for your problem

Comment: It looks like a neat place to put a view. You can prepare a view which will include the `WHERE IsDeleted = False`, name it 'OnlyActiveUsers' and then query against this view in the application when needed...

Comment: On the other hand, doing it explicitly in all queries makes it clear you only want the active users. And later you may want to see deleted users too (for admin purposes for example). After all, this is business logic, not data logic. This would probably also be the solution with least impact. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by C# but it would really be the wrong tool for the job.

[Create a view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187956.aspx) in the database that includes this statement and only work with the view from now on. You can even enforce this by not granting privileges on the table any more.

Comment: "This can be solved by C# but it would really be the wrong tool for the job." - we created a view but could you please explain how it can be solved by C#? Thank you.